# Play 2.1 and reactivemongo 0.8 count documents

Tags: json, mongodb, playframework, playframework-2.1, reactivemongo

I have Play 2.1 app which uses `MongoDB` via `Reactivemongo 0.8 plugin`. In my app I use aproach described **[here](http://mandubian.com/2013/01/13/JSON-Coast-to-Coast/)**  without using models

I have method which returns all documents from mongodb where "type" equals getType parameter in function getTypeAll for example `{"type": "computer"}` which works fine.

```
def getTypeAll(getType: String) = Action {

val validatedType = getType.replaceAll("-"," ")
val q = QueryBuilder().query(toType.writes(validatedType))

Async {

 val f = collection.find[JsValue](q)

 f.toList.map{ 

  jsonp => 


  Ok( Json.toJson(jsonp) )   

    }
  }
}
```

toType is written as `val toType = OWrites[String]{ s => Json.obj("type" -> s) }` and val collection is defined as `lazy val collection = db("mycollection")`

The problem is that I am not able to write method which will get count of documents where "type" equals the same parameter.

```
def countTypeAll(getType: String) = Action {

}
```

and return it as json like {"typecount": 45}

I was looking on every example I found but without success. I think that what I want is something like `val c = collection.find[JsValue](q).count()`

but it gives error saying `value size is not a member of reactivemongo.api.DefaultCollection`

Can anybody tell me how count all documents where value of element equals specified value?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

With ReactiveMongo 0.8 you have to use the [`Count`](http://reactivemongo.org/releases/0.8/api/index.html#reactivemongo.core.commands.Count) command to achieve that.

```
val futureCount = db.command(Count(collection.name, Some(BSONDocument("type" -> BSONString(s)))))
futureCount.map { count => // count is an Int
  // do some stuff
}
```

There is no way to give it directly a JSON document though. But you can transform explicitly your JSON document to `BSONDocument` if you don't want to write BSONDocument yourself.